# DAO Testing - Spring + JPA Autowiring issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use Spring on top of JPA with a Hibernate implementation. I'd like to use Spring for at least Annotation, Autowiring & Transaction management. I keep running into the below issue though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My GenericDAO Implementation:

```
package gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public abstract class GenericDAO<K, T extends Serializable>
    implements IGenericDAO<K, T> 
{
    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public GenericDAO()
    {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    public T findOne(K id)
    {
        if(isEmpty(id)) { return null; }

        return this.entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll()
    {
        return this.entityManager.createQuery("from " + entityClass.getName()).getResultList();
    }

    public void create(T entity)
    {  
        this.entityManager.persist(entity);
        this.entityManager.close();
    }

    public void update(T entity)
    {
        this.entityManager.merge(entity);
        this.entityManager.flush();
        this.entityManager.close();
    }

    public void delete(T entity)
    {
        this.entityManager.remove(entity);
        this.entityManager.close();
    }

    public void deleteById(K id)
    {
        T entity = findOne(id);
        delete(entity);
    }

    /**
     * Utility method to determine if objects is empty or all elements are null for optimization purposes.
     *
     * @param objects the objects
     * @return true, if is empty
     */
    protected boolean isEmpty(Object...objects) {
        if(objects.length == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        for(Object o : objects) {
            if(o != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

The DAO itself:

```
package gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao;

import gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.model.Practice;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * The Class PracticeDAO for CRUD operations for Practice data.
 */
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PracticeDAO extends GenericDAO<String, Practice> 
    implements IPracticeDAO
{
    public PracticeDAO(){}

    /** The Constant logger. */
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(PracticeDAO.class);

    @Override
    public Practice findPersonByFullName(String full_Name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

The test DAO: **Not all tests included for space** (In src/test/java)

```
package gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao;

import gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.model.Practice;

import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.AssertionFailedError;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml")
@Transactional
public class PracticeDAOTest extends TestCase
{
    @Autowired
    public PracticeDAO testPracticeDAO;

    public void setPracticeDAO(PracticeDAO testPracticeDAO) {
        this.testPracticeDAO = testPracticeDAO;
    }

    boolean doit = true;

    @Test
    public void testCreatePracticeDAO(){
        if(doit){
        Practice practice = generatePractice();
        String porg = practice.getParentOrgName();
        String pid = practice.getPracticeId();

        //create
        try {
                 testPracticeDAO.create(practice);
                 String pratice_id = testPracticeDAO.findOne(pid).getPracticeId();
                 assertEquals("Practice id check", pid, pratice_id);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new AssertionFailedError("Practice Save failed");
            }
        // test update
        try{
                practice.setSiteName("baltimore");
                if(testPracticeDAO.findOne(pid) !=null){
                testPracticeDAO.update(practice);
                String site_Name = testPracticeDAO.findOne(pid).getSiteName();
                assertEquals("Practice Site check", "baltimore", site_Name);
                }

            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new AssertionFailedError("Practice update failed!");
            }
}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="ApplicationEntityManager">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                 value="xxxxxxxxx"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxxxxx"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxxx"/>
        </properties> 

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

applicationContext.xml (In src/main/resources)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ApplicationEntityManager" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="xxxxxxx" />
        <property name="username" value="xxxxxxx" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxxxxx" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao"/>

    <!-- Add new DAOs here -->
    <bean id="practiceDAO" class="gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO"/>
    <bean id="testPracticeDAO" class="gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO"/>

    <!-- Add new Managers here -->
</beans>
```

And the STACKTRACE:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAOTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAOTest.testPracticeDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAOTest.testPracticeDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 34 more


Results :

Tests in error: 
  testCreatePracticeDAO(gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAOTest): Error creating bean with name 'gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAOTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAOTest.testPracticeDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  testFindAllPractices(gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAOTest): Error creating bean with name 'gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAOTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAOTest.testPracticeDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Is the name `applicationContext.xml` or`application-context.xml`? I hope that is not the issue.

Comment: BTW, are you using cglib proxy or JDK Dynamic proxy?

Comment: It was applicationContext.xml, sorry I corrected the header in my post.

I'm not using any sort of proxy. I haven't seen any usage or mention of it so far in the examples I've found. Would that be giving me the issue with the beans or affect transactions later on down the line?

Comment: Try autowiring on `IPracticeDAO` instead. I'm sure that will work.

Comment: Remove these lines. You are using annotations and have specified packages to scan so you do not need to define beans in your xml.  Although probably not the cause of your current issue will cause problems at some point: 
    <!-- Add new DAOs here -->
    <bean id="practiceDAO" class="gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO"/>
    <bean id="testPracticeDAO" class="gov.cms.cicdim.cpc.data.dao.PracticeDAO"/>

    <!-- Add new Managers here -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring [declarative transactions are implemented using proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies). By default if the proxied class implements an interface, it uses JDK Dynamic proxy, which is what is being used here, as `PracticeDAO` implements `IPracticeDAO`.

The proxy created by spring implements the same interface `IPracticeDAO`, and a bean of that proxy is registered. And since you're autowiring on `PracticeDAO`, the proxy bean could not be autowired, as instances of sibling classes are not compatible. That is why you should almost always use `@Autowired` annotation on interface type, rather than implementing class type.

In your case, try autowiring on `IPracticeDAO` instead of `PracticeDAO`, and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks! This appears to have worked. Though now, it doesn't appear that the test entity is being persisted to the database so is something misconfigured for my Spring Transactions?

Comment: Why do you have 2 `<tx:annotation-driven>` tags in your context file. Remove the first one.

Comment: I saw that in another example on here. It frankly confused me as well...

Removed it and am still not seeing the entity being persisted.

Comment: Figured it out! I had the testDAO marked as @Transactional as well and this part of documentation says that's a no-no :

"What is important to keep in mind is that, if the transactional bean is implementing an interface, by default the proxy will be a Java Dynamic Proxy. This means that only external method calls that come in through the proxy will be intercepted – any self-invocation calls will not start any transaction – even if the method is annotated with @Transactional."

Removing that and it works fine now! Thanks again!